# Unity game debugging on Xcode

Tags: unity, ios, debugging, xcode

This question has two parts:

**1.** How to get meaningful information out of Xcode crash logs? The game runs fine on the editor but when running on an iOS device it crashes and then gives information like this:
[image]

How can I dig out which script actually causes this?

**2.** Which Xcode debugging tools are available for Unity games? There are plenty of them mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/DebugYourApp/DebugYourApp.html). Especially the frame capture and Instruments profiling seem very handy.